# Разная стилистика вывода новостей на WP

Tags: wordpress

Друзья, добрый день.
Подскажите как реализовать такую выдачу новостей http://joxi.ru/v29NVQdIoQ6RAG , получается есть три стилистики, от чего отталкиваться?

Comment: спросите у заказчика по какому принципу должен меняться стиль

Comment: Ну это будут выводиться так новости на главной с одной категории, так же будут выводится в той категории. Новость создается и выводиться в таком порядке и дизайне как на скрине.

Comment: в чем конкретно трудность? когда вы получаете список новостей от WP - вы их перебираете. И можете считать. Дальше идут условия типа `if ($i == 1) {}` ну и там вставляете соответствующие стилизованные блоки